# How to get Relative path in an XML file?

Tags: xml

I have an XML file named `set.xml` under a folder named `A`.
Under the same folder `A`, I have an application folder called `test`.

In my `set.xml`, I have a node

```
<ApplicationPath>Here I need to put the path of my application</ApplicationPath>
```

So both `set.xml` and my application `test` are under folder `A`.
I want to get to my application test through that node, I have tried :

```
<ApplicationPath>./test</ApplicationPath>
<ApplicationPath>../test</ApplicationPath>
<ApplicationPath>test</ApplicationPath>
<ApplicationPath>\test</ApplicationPath>
```

But nothing seems to work, it always show the wrong path.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Please accept the answer if this your questions was answered in a helpful manner.

Comment: Actually your answer didn't quiet help

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is simply defining an XML element named `ApplicationPath`. However, a piece of software that processes your `set.xml` file does not have access to any further semantic behavior. Basically an XML processor will just see the `ApplicationPath` element with a string data type in it. From that point on XML can't really do anything more for you as it's just a simple element. Therefore, you have to do any kind of further processing such as relative path resolution etc. yourself manually after parsing the XML.

However, you might want to have a look at XLink which is an XML markup language for creating internal and external links within XML documents.

It depends a bit on what your goal is. Your XML processing toolchain needs to support XLink (which is not uncommon).
If that is not an option you're basically left with doing what you already did: Manually handle the paths yourself.

Useful material:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLink)
- [Version 1.1 Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/xlink11/)

Comment: Should I mention that my application is under the src/main/resources of a maven application.